# How do I change Background Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to change divs background-image with jquery. The photo I need to use as background-image is first image of photoset.

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
</div>
```

JS

```
$('div').css("background-image", "url(" + $('div img:first-child').attr('src'); + ")");
```

CODEPEN

http://codepen.io/aleksitappura/pen/nKehv

Comment: You don't have extension on images, also remove semicolon from url.

Comment: You got `.attr('src'); + ` kill the `;` so it should look like `$('div').css("background-image", "url(" + $('div img:first-child').attr('src') + ")");` I have voted on closing this question due to your typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
   $('div').css("background-image", "url(" + $('div img:first-child').attr('src') + ")");
```

small `typo` error after `.attr('src');`

just remove `;`

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjCvK)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the console to detect scripting errors. The code you posted is producing an error because the `;` behind the `$('div img:first-child').attr('src')` is unexpected and just wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('div').css("background-image", "url('" + $('div img:first-child').attr('src') + "')");
```